# Have I understood how OpenSSH and X509 works?

Tags: openssh, openssl, x509

We want to test a connection with OpenSSH using X509 certificates using [pkixssh fork from Roumen Petrov](https://roumenpetrov.info/secsh/index.html).

I don't understand really how the full authentication works and specially how to create the certificats with X509 standards for public key certificates validation.

So I will explain first how I understand it and the full process I will follow to test a connection between a **"client"** and a **"server"** machine with PKIXSSH fork of OpenSSH, using X509 certificates. To make the test we will use a third machine, that we will call **"control machine"**, machine that will act as a "Certification Authority"

To understand how it works I have read the following documents:

- ["Scalable and secure access with SSH"](https://engineering.fb.com/security/scalable-and-secure-access-with-ssh/), from Facebook: very useful to understand what is the role of a certification authority in the validation of public keys.
- ["HOWTO SSH & X509 certificates"](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-441064.html), from Gentoo discussion forums: A really good, and needed, howto
- ["Certificats x509 pour SSH"](https://linux-attitude.fr/post/certificats-x509-pour-ssh), post from the blog "Linux Attitude": another howto, this one in french

In a quick summary, and if I have correctly understood, this is how it works:

- X509 is a standard to sign public keys. Signed public keys are considered valid if the Certification Authority is known.
- We can sign public keys for hosts and users
- With X509 certificates we can sign in a OpenSSH server without using passwords and without using the traditional OpenSSH private-public key authentication. This means that **no user ublic keys must be copied on destination servers**.
- If we use X509 certificates for hosts then the client will trust the OpenSSH server without the need of manually add its public key in the known_host file.

We want to make two tests:

- Test the connection for an user from the client machine to the server using a X509 certificate
- In a second step add authentification for the server host

I have arrived to the conclusion that the next steps must be followed

- In the "control" machine:

  - Configure and create the keys for our test certification authority
  - Send the public certification authority key to the OpenSSH daemon of the "server" machine, so our CA is recognised
- In the "client" machine:

  - create the private key and public key for the user
  - send the public key to the control machine to be signed by the c.a.
  - add the certificate to the private key file so it will be presented to the server

At this point everything should be in its place, so we could test the connection

Have I understood it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

At last I have understood and tested the connection :-).

I have written a post on a blog I have just deployed (in a quick & dirty way, the blog is simple and not very pretty, but useful).

You can read a full description of the test in the article ["OpenSSH with X509 certificates HOW TO"](http://tech.ciges.net/blog/openssh-with-x509-certificates-how-to/)

Thanks a lot to Roumen Petrov for his answers to my email in the mailing list of the product.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The provided link seems to be offline. Is it mirrored or available anyplace else?

Comment: Hello! Yes, I know. The OVH fire that affected data center in Strasbourg hitted the machine where my webs are hosted :-|. When I have time I will redeploy them again (in some weeks, I think).